# Populating spinner data from json dynamically

Tags: java, mobile, android-studio-3.0

I'm new to android programming and I'm having a problem with my codes so basically I want to populate my data that is coming from the server to my spinner view. My issue is that I want to set it dynamic so that whenever the server updates it will do the same with my spinner.

Here is my code:

```
/** an ID for the spinner **/
spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

/** publisher definition with its type of message**/
waypointlistData = new SubscribedData<>();
final Type waypointlistType = new TypeToken<SubscribedData<WaypointList>>() {
}.getType();


/** A method to parse a jsonstring to waypoint list **/
private List<Waypoint> getWayPointListFromJsonString(String json){
    List<Waypoint> wayPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray wayPointJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("msg").getJSONArray("waypoints");
        for (int i = 0; i < wayPointJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject wayPointJsonObject = wayPointJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Parse name
            String name = wayPointJsonObject.getString("name");

            // Parse pose to get position and orientation;
            JSONObject poseJsonObject = wayPointJsonObject.getJSONObject("pose");

            // Parse position form pose
            JSONObject positionJsonObject = poseJsonObject.getJSONObject("position");
            Position position = new Position();
            position.x = positionJsonObject.getFloat("x");
            position.y = positionJsonObject.getFloat("y");
            position.z = positionJsonObject.getFloat("z");

            // Parse orientation from pose.
            JSONObject orientationJsonObject = poseJsonObject.getJSONObject("orientation");
            Orientation orientation = new Orientation();
            orientation.x = orientationJsonObject.getFloat("x");
            orientation.y = orientationJsonObject.getFloat("y");
            orientation.z = orientationJsonObject.getFloat("z");
            orientation.w = orientationJsonObject.getFloat("w");

            Pose pose = new Pose();
            pose.position = position;
            pose.orientation = orientation;

            Waypoint wayPoint = new Waypoint();
            wayPoint.name = name;
            wayPoint.pose = pose;
            wayPoints.add(wayPoint);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return wayPoints;
}

// This is the json string returned from server.
String jsonString = "{\"topic\": \"/waypoints\", \"msg\": {\"waypoints\": [{\"header\": {\"stamp\": {\"secs\": 0, \"nsecs\": 0}, \"frame_id\": \"map\", \"seq\": 0}, \"pose\": {\"position\": {\"y\": -140.901899144836, \"x\": 44.36469369653882, \"z\": 0.0}, \"orientation\": {\"y\": 0.0, \"x\": 0.0, \"z\": 0.5062775131960053, \"w\": 0.8623706161692133}}, \"name\": \"A\"}, {\"header\": {\"stamp\": {\"secs\": 0, \"nsecs\": 0}, \"frame_id\": \"map\", \"seq\": 0}, \"pose\": {\"position\": {\"y\": -102.30524463734227, \"x\": 51.282396271771304, \"z\": 0.0}, \"orientation\": {\"y\": 0.0, \"x\": 0.0, \"z\": 0.6926372547579506, \"w\": 0.721286096719859}}, \"name\": \"B\"}]}, \"op\": \"publish\"}";

// This will convert the json string to list of WayPoint
List<Waypoint> wayPoints = getWayPointListFromJsonString(jsonString);

// Create adapter for spinner
SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wayPoints);

spin.setAdapter(adapter);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p, long id) {
        Waypoint wayPoint = (Waypoint) parent.getItemAtPosition(p);

        // Process position here
        Position position = wayPoint.pose.position;

        // Process orientation here
        Orientation orientation = wayPoint.pose.orientation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});

    /** a set of the waypoints popup window **/
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .6), (int) (height * .6));


  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just set the response of your api call to your jsonString

Comment: @Ankit hey just like I mentioned I'm still a beginner, how do i do that?

Comment: you can use any library for api calling like volley,retrofit or okhttp

Comment: @Ankit yeah I've tried retrofit but my server's connection is through the rosbridge(ROS). is it possible to use retrofit and make the URL calling as the ip address?

Comment: may be you require web socket for that

Comment: @Ankit i do have the websocket now. Im receiving an update data from my server through that connection. my problem is displaying them to my spinner dynamically.

Comment: webscoket run on non-ui thread so to access ui inside socket you have to use runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // you can access ui here
            }
        });

Comment: @Ankit i dont get it but thanks